# Click event by name not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck with very small issue.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn-danger" name="ignore" id="45"><i class= "fa fa-close"> </i> Ignore </a>

<a title="ignore1" data-original-title="ignore1" id="14" name="ignore1" class="btn btn-small btn-danger" href="#"><i class="fa fa-close"> </i> Ignore1 </a>
```

You can see  two hyperlinks and here is the jQuery code.

```
$("a[name='ignore1']").click(function() {
    alert('Test Ok');
});

$("a[name='ignore']").click(function() {

    alert('Ok');
});
```

I am not getting alert. Do you have any advice on this?

Comment: Put you `js` in `$(document).ready(function(){ /*your code*/ })`.

Comment: tried that but no luck.

Comment: Ok then I think you missed `jQuery` reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the DOM is loaded.

```
$(function(){
    $("a[name='ignore']").click(function(){
        alert('yesss');
    });     
});
```

If you are dynamicaly loading the elements you may want to use `on()` which will dynamicaly attach the event:

```
$(document).on("click","a[name='ignore']", function() {
    alert('yesss');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. voted up.

Comment: $(document).on("click","a[name='ignore']", function() { this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

With `document.ready` it is working. Check this out:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[name='ignore1']").click(function() {
    alert('Test Ok');
  });

  $("a[name='ignore']").click(function() {

    alert('Ok');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn-danger" name="ignore" id="45"><i class= "fa fa-close"> </i> Ignore </a>

<a title="ignore1" data-original-title="ignore1" id="14" name="ignore1" class="btn btn-small btn-danger" href="#"><i class="fa fa-close"> </i> Ignore1 </a>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. voted up.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $("a[name='ignore1']").click(function() {

        alert('Test Ok');
    });

    $("a[name='ignore']").click(function() {

        alert('Ok');
    });

});
```

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn-danger" name="ignore" id="45"><i class= "fa fa-close"> </i> Ignore </a>

<a title="ignore1" data-original-title="ignore1" id="14" name="ignore1" class="btn btn-small btn-danger" href="#"><i class="fa fa-close"> </i> Ignore1 </a>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. voted up.